# In how many ways can the letters in the word "PROBABILITY" be arranged using the following restrcitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can the letters in the word "PROBABILITY" be arranged if the first letter must be "B" and the last letter cannot be an "O", "A", or "I"?

Answer (score 2):

The word $PROBABILITY$ has eleven letters, of which $1$ is a $P$, $1$ is an $R$, $1$ is an O, $2$ are $B$s, $1$ is an $A$, $2$ are $I$s, $1$ is an $L$, $1$ is a $T$, and $1$ is an $I$.  Hence, we have eleven positions to fill.  Since the first letter must be a $B$, the first position can be filled in one way.  Since there are nine distinct letters in the word $PROBABILITY$ and the last letter cannot be an $A$, $O$, or $I$, the last position can be filled in $6$ ways.  Two of the remaining nine positions must be filled with $I$s, which can be done in $\binom{9}{2}$ ways.  Since we have already placed both $I$s and one of the $B$s, the remaining seven letters are distinct, so they can be placed in the remaining seven positions in $7!$ ways.  Hence, the number of admissible arrangements of the letters of the word $PROBABILIY$ is 
$$1 \cdot 6 \cdot \binom{9}{2} \cdot 7! = 6 \cdot \frac{9!}{2!7!} \cdot 7! = 3 \cdot 9! = 1,088,640$$

Comment: can we use $^{n}C_{r}$ for choosing $r$ identical items

Comment: We are choosing two positions for the $I$s.  The positions are *not* identical.

Answer (score 2):

first letter should be $B$ (in $1$ way )and  last letter can't be $O,A,I $ so, last letter can be $P,R,B,Y,L,T$ in $6$ ways and remaining $9$ letters  can be arranged in between in $\dfrac{9!}{2!}$ ways (division by $2!$ because of two identical I's)

so, total number of ways $=1\times 6\times\dfrac{9!}{2!}=1088640  $ ways

Answer (score 0):

Solved 2 x 6 x (9!) = 4,354,560.
My error was using a 7 where the 6 was, forgot to consider the 2 at the beginning

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  You have not explained how you got your answer, so I am not sure what you did.  Since the two $I$s are indistinguishable, you should have divided by $2$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  The expectation at this site is that you include your attempt in the question itself, which you can do by clicking on the edit button at the bottom of your question.  Explaining how you arrived at your answer helps users of this site identify any errors you may have made.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.